# stickyHeaders_attachTo is not working in Magnific Popup

Tags: tablesorter, magnific-popup

I need fixed the header for tablesorter table that it's shows on magnific popup

I tried Below code to but it's not working for me

```
enter code here

      $("#itemlist").tablesorter({
         widthFixed : true,


       widgets: [ 'zebra', 'cssStickyHeaders', 'filter' ],

       widgetOptions: {
     stickyHeaders_attachTo: $('.wrapper'), or //both are not working

    cssStickyHeaders_attachTo      : '.wrapper',//
   cssStickyHeaders_addCaption    : true
}

      });
```

Comment: Try using `cssStickyHeaders_attachTo`

Comment: i already tried that not working

Answer (score 0):

In this case, it looks like the magnific popup adds it's own wrapper (`.mfp-wrap`). So if you target it instead of the element wrapping the table, it works ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/abkNM/4615/)):

```
$(function () {

    $('.open-popup-link').magnificPopup({
        type: 'inline',
        midClick: true,
        callbacks: {
            open: function () {
                // Will fire when this exact popup is opened
                // this - is Magnific Popup object
                $('table').tablesorter({
                    theme: 'blue',
                    widgets: ['zebra', 'filter', 'cssStickyHeaders'],
                    widgetOptions: {
                        // jQuery selector or object to attach sticky header to
                        cssStickyHeaders_attachTo: '.mfp-wrap',
                        cssStickyHeaders_addCaption: true
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: hi mottie in your demo your popup movie to window than stickty header it's worked but in my scenior popup will not moved to window it's has fixed position  like this http://jsfiddle.net/QQRL5/2/

Comment: So, you're not using magnific? Can you provide a demo of this popup.

Comment: no my popup is maginific popup   $('.popup-with-zoom-anim').magnificPopup({
            type: 'inline',
            fixedContentPos: false,
            fixedBgPos: true,
            overflowY: 'auto',
            closeBtnInside: true,
            preloader: false,
            midClick: true,
            removalDelay: 300,
            mainClass: 'my-mfp-zoom-in',
        });

Comment: Ok, if you don't fix the content, then don't use the `cssStickyHeaders_attachTo` option ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/abkNM/4701/))